# Get selected checkboxes on form post ( c# razor)

Tags: c#, forms, razor

I am adding checkboxes to html using foreach.

```
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="@item.Value" value="@item.Value" />
    @item.Value
}
```

I need to get values from selected on form post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the best way would be to use the helper:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.Checkbox("item[" + i + "]")
    @list[i].Value
}
```

In the controller, make sure to bind to a list of `item`s:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<bool> item) {}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EditorTemplates** to handle this.

For example, You want to create a student creation screen where you need to provide check boxes for course selection, you will create a viewmodel like this

```
public class CreateStudentVM
{        
    public string Name { set; get; }      
    public List<CourseSelection> Courses { set; get; }

    public CreateStudentVM()
    {
        this.Courses=new List<CourseSelection>();
    }
}
public class CourseSelection
{
    public int CourseId { set; get; }
    public string CourseName { set; get; }
    public bool IsSelected { set; get; }
}
```

and in your GET action method,you create an object of `CreateStudentVM` class,initialize the `Courses` property with a list of courses (for the checkbox items)

```
private List<CourseSelection> GetCourses()
{
    //Hard coded for demo. Replace with entries from db
    return new List<CourseSelection>()
    {
        new CourseSelection {CourseId = 1, CourseName = "CS"},
        new CourseSelection {CourseId = 2, CourseName = "MT"}
    };
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new CreateCustomerVM();
    vm.Courses = GetCourses();
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now we need to create an Editor template. Go to the Views folder,Select the directory for your current controller and add a subfolder called `EditorTemplates`. Add a partial view under that called `CourseSelection.cshtml`

[image]

Now Add the below code the new partial view we created.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.CourseSelection
<div>
    @Model.CourseName
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(s=>s.IsSelected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.CourseId)
</div>
```

The name of the editortemplate partial view should be same as the type we are using to bind to it (in this case `CourseSelection`)

Now we will use `Html.EditorFor` helper method in the main view which is strongly typed to `CreateStudentVM`

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.CreateStudentVM
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Courses)

    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

This should render your page with checkboxes for each items in the Courses collection. When you post your form back, you can check the `IsSelected` property of Courses collection.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CreateStudentVM model)
{
    if (model != null)
    {
        // TO DO : Save and Redirect
        // PRG Pattern
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

[image]

Cheers !